# How to print the output of running program started by crontab job to a file on daily basis

Tags: linux, shell, cron

A script `start.sh` is registered in `crontab` to run on daily basis

But I'd like to save the output of the program to a file, like `cronlog-yyyyMMdd.log`

I tried the following but failed:

```
16 10 * * 1-5 ~/start.sh >> ~/cronlog/$(date+"\%F")-cron.log 2>&1
```

Anyone help me?

Comment: Do not use relative paths. Use full ones: `/bin/sh /home/youruser/start.sh` and the same for the output file.

Comment: you'll need a space between `date` and the `+` format specifier. Good luck.

Comment: @fedorqui May I ask why relative paths shouldn't been used?

Comment: @shellter space is the key. Thanks. You should answer below so that I could mark your words as answer.

Comment: @user838204 : Thanks, I have posted a full answer. Glad that it helped you.

Comment: @user838204 this is because the crontab runs in a reduced environment, so you cannot expect it to know where are your files in a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fully-qualified paths to all programs and files that are mentioned eliminate a whole class of errors from debugging issues with crontab entries.  In this particular case, doing so would have only proved there were no problems with PATH issues in your crontab entry.

Your issue is that you need a space char between the `date` cmd and it's formatting argument string, instead of

```
$(date+"\%F")
#0    ^v
$(date +"\%F")
```

I commend you for your good crontab debug etiquette; capturing std-err and std-out to a file gives you 1. proof that your command ran when you expected it to (or if you have an error in your time specification, it will show you when the cmd did run). 2. you avoid having your localhost email box filling up with msgs from the cron daemon. 3 Any std-err msgs that were generated are also captured and are in generally in sync and time order with std-out messages.

IHTH.

Comment: I understand the benefit of outputting the `crontab` result to a file but only a file is not a good idea. That's why I want to output the result to different file

Answer (score 0):

```
16 10 * * 1-5 ~/start.sh >> ~/cronlog/$(date +"\%F")-cron.log
```

Edit: as explained in comments, this answers the question by correcting a typo in the asker's attempted entry

Comment: While this may be a solution to the question, can you please provide a commentary as to what it is doing?

Comment: Question it self has the answer, I was only correcting it's typo

Comment: Then it should have been an edit suggestion or a comment. Not an snswer, as it's not an answer.

Comment: Next time I'll use comments. I'm new to this site. BTW thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Thank you. You may want to check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) too.

Comment: Having looked closer at the question and the answers, your post was correct, but needed an explanation of what the problem was. Reading your answer, it was not immediately obvious that it was just a missing space.

Comment: yes you're right. it's not an answer if the viewer can't understand it event if it's the correct answer. Answer should have been clear. My bad